# SOLVED: Can't install elementary OS Loki: nouveau init failed (MMIO write fault)

Tags: release-loki, system-installation

I wanted to install elementary OS Loki in dual boot with my win10. For information, I have a old motherboard mode with **legacy bios**, I hope is not a problem to install elementary OS Loki.

I used Rufus and followed the tutorial (just in case I missed something), after selecting the USB stick, and before getting any install menu, I got this:

[image: elementary OS installation error]

Remark: I tried to install Ubuntu to check my computer, I got the same error with > Ubuntu 16.X. But it's working with all Ubuntu (I tested the liveUSB mode only) <= 15.X, and finally it's working with elementary OS Freya (based on Ubuntu 14.X, if I remember well).

I didn't find out what change between these version yet :/ Any idea ?

**EDIT:**
Right, I've found in this thread the beginning of my answer: https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=226400.
So, something's wrong with my graphic card driver (nvidia GTX 970). However, even after many try, I didn't succeed to add this "*modprobe.blacklist=nouveau*" to the kernel parameter yet.

Comment: Have you trying to boot with `nomodeset` parameter to recovery mode? Before this, you must install nvidia drivers and blacklist nouveau.

Answer (score 1):

Got it !

Following the thread I mentioned in my last edit, I followed this guide https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Kernel_parameters, and added the statement:
**modprobe.blacklist=nouveau** in all *.cfg files contained in the (USB-STICK)"/boot/grub" directory.

Voilà :)

Comment: could you accept your own answer as correct, as it will get bumped to community every now-and-then if it's not answered? :)